# Puzzled at need for closure re Win 7 issue

Tags: discussion

How is it that  Ramhound, Jakuje, and others, closed the question

[WIN7: How can Windows Update Agent be “resuming” when I've set “Never check for updates”?](https://superuser.com/questions/1137123/win7-how-can-windows-update-agent-be-resuming-when-ive-set-never-check-for)

...as “too broad” after they had themselves (repeatedly) edited and reformatted it?

If you were moved to mess with it so extensively, was it not incumbent on you to advise me that it was at risk for these reasons?

Or is it embarrassment that no super-users can venture an answer to what at root is surely a rather simple issue of WIN7 log-files frequently *resuming* (unbidden) and *pausing* the sometimes-dreaded Windows *Automatic Updates*, in spite of having set *Never check for updates* ?

Seeker (after clarity)

Comment: Alternate link to [WIN7: How can Windows Update Agent be “resuming” when I've set “Never check for updates”?](http://nerdanswer.com/answer.php?q=1441259)

Comment: @DavidPostill and karel Thanks to you both.

Answer (score 2):

The question was likely closed as too broad because there are multiple (two or three) related but distinct questions in the one post:

- "How can the Windows Update Agent resume when checking for updates is disabled?" This is the title question and also appears in the body. I believe "what's going on?" refers to this question.
- "What updates could be installed while it's resumed?" This seems to be your main concern.
- "Am I at risk of anything?" This also appears in the body, but it might mean the same as the above, or it might be a security question.

The third might be the same as the second; I'm not quite sure. We prefer that each question cover exactly one well-defined topic.

The people who edited your question probably didn't modify its meaning because they also were not sure which of those questions you're interested in. They did see a way they could help you get answers: by improving your question's formatting so it's easier to read. Personally, I would love it if everyone would leave an explanatory comment when voting to close questions, but it's not required.

I don't believe questions are closed out of "embarrassment." Indeed, questions that are well-written but surprisingly tough to answer frequently receive good quantities of upvotes.

I suggest that you look through our [tour](https://superuser.com/tour) to get a summary of how our site differs from normal Internet forums. Specifically, we remove things like taglines and signatures, since your usercard is your signature. We also use the tags section to classify questions, as opposed to including the tags in the title.

Since you're still interested in your original question, I've voted to undelete it. I believe you as the post owner can do the same, then it will take only one more 10K+ user to restore it. In the meantime, I suggest you be even more specific about what you want. Then I'm sure people will be able to help you.

Comment: I've tried to modify the question to meet the rules, using the link "If this question can be reworded to fit the rules in the help center, please edit your question." but it appears to still be closed. My only other route is to post it as a new question, but I suspect that will trigger a ban, so I will wait to see what happens

Comment: @Seeker Thanks for editing your question, it's much better now! I've put in some adjustments of my own and I cast the first reopen vote. Unfortunately, I'm pretty sure deleted questions don't appear in the reopen review queue. Hopefully another 10K+ user will cast the last undelete vote, then the reviewers can see it.